# How can I change this query after migrating to ASP.Net Core 3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

> Could not be translated... See go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038

Can't I use `Include()` anymore? Is it better I start to using raw SQL commands?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    id = 1;
  }

  var pianoContext = _context.Product
    .Include(p => p.IdProductCategoryNavigation)
    .Include(p => p.IdProductTamNavigation)
    .Include(p => p.IdProductTypeNavigation)
    .Where(m => m.IdProductCategory == id || m.IdProductCategoryNavigation.IdPa.Value == 1)
    .Where(m => m.IsAt.Equals(true))
    .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
    .Select(m => m.First());

  if (pianoContext == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }
  return View(await pianoContext.ToListAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't I use Include() anymore? Is it better I start to using raw SQL commands?

That's not related to `Include()` but because you're using `GroupBy(m=> m.Name)`. See [breaking chagnes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client).

Here's a description about `Groupby` quoted from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators):

> *The SQL GROUP BY is restrictive too. It requires you to group only by scalar values.The projection can only contain grouping key columns or any aggregate applied over a column. EF Core identifies this pattern and translates it to the server*

To fix that issue, you should use a`GroupBy()` that can be translated into SQL:

```cs
// a lazy query that will be used to query the ids of Product
var theProductIds = 
    _context.Product
    .Where(m => m.IdProductCategory == id || m.IdProductCategoryNavigation.IdPa.Value == 1)
    .Where(m => m.IsAt.Equals(true))
    .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
    .Select(m => m.Min(p=>p.Id));

// a query that includes all the related navigation properties
var products = await _context.Product
    .Where(p => theProductIds.Contains(p.Id)) 
    .Include(p => p.IdProductCategoryNavigation)
    .Include(p => p.IdProductTamNavigation)
    .Include(p => p.IdProductTypeNavigation)
    .ToListAsync();

if(products.Count==0){ return NotFound(); }
return View(products);
```

The above query will be translated into a SQL statement like below:

```
SELECT [p].[Id], [p].[CategoryId], [p].[Name], ...
FROM [Product] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [ProductCategory] AS [p0] ON [p].[CategoryId] = [p0].[Id]
INNER JOIN ...
WHERE [p].[Id] IN (
    SELECT MIN([p1].[Id])
    FROM [Product] AS [p1]
    INNER JOIN [ProductCategory] AS [p2] ON [p1].[CategoryId] = [p2].[Id]
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY [p1].[Name]
)
```